# How to assign Multiple return statements based on conditions in Python lambda function

Tags: python

**I have a data like this, and I want to add String with comma separated and sum int values.**

```
data=[{"string": "x","int": 1},
      {"string": "y","int": 2},
      {"string": "z","int": 3}]
```

I'am expecting an output some thing like this.

**Output:**

```
{ "string":"x,y,z","int":"6"}
```

I tried using reduce function

```
func = lambda x, y: dict((m, n + y[m]) for m, n in x.items() )
print reduce(func, data)
```

and i am getting something like this.

```
{"string": "xyz", "int": "6"}
```

How to get string with comma separated.

Comment: Don't use a lambda for that.

Comment: @Goyo then? what should i do to iterate over the dictionary if i am having 50 columns to sum...

Comment: Use a normal function `def func(x, y):`. It will give you more flexibility to do whatever is needed. Only use lambdas for very simple functions. If it is not working and you do not know how to fix it then it is not very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func = lambda x, y: dict((m, n + y[m]) for m, n in x.items() )
```

You need a custom function to replace `n+y[m]` (let's say `custom_add(a,b)`), which,

- if arguments are integers to return algebraic sum of them
- if arguments are strings, to join them with ',' and return final string

let's implement it.

```
def custom_join(a,b):
    arr = list((a,b))
    return sum(arr) if is_int_array(arr) else ','.join(arr)
```

we have no `is_int_array/1` yet. let's do it now.

```
def is_int_array(arr):
    return all(i for i in map(is_int, arr))
```

no `is_int/1`. let's do it

```
def is_int(e):
    return isinstance(e, int)
```

do the same things for strings

```
def is_str(e):
    return isinstance(e, str)

def is_str_array(arr):
    return all(i for i in map(is_str, arr))
```

Summing all of them - https://repl.it/LPRR

OK, this is insane but when you try to implement `functional-only` approach, you need to be ready such situations -)))

Comment: Thanq @marmeladze

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) with some [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) like this:

```
res = {"string": ','.join(d['string'] for d in data), "int": sum(d['int'] for d in data)}
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
{'int': 6, 'string': 'x,y,z'}
```

Comment: I have around 30 integer type keys and 20 String keys, so i want to iterate dictionary through reduce. It would be helpful if it is in lambda.